# flatpage в django. Одна страница - два шаблона

Tags: python, django

Собственно, ситуация такая. Есть в базе данных страница. Мне нужно выводить её по двум адресам (один вариант для web, другой для мобильных устройств). Отсюда вопрос, как указать в роутинге (urls) шаблон для страницы? Ибо то имя шаблона, которая хранится в базе, будет использоваться в web. Пытаюсь написать роутинг для мобильных устройств и не знаю, как дать понять flatpages, что шаблон для мобильных нужно брать другой...

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. это `flatpage` то `url` изменить нельзя, следовательно, если использование `flatpages` принципиально - то нужно вынести логику определения мобильного клиента в саму страницу. Наиболее адекватно (хотя такое решение в принципе не подпадает под это определение) это можно сделать написав свой [фильтр](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/howto/custom-template-tags.html#writing-custom-template-filters) который принимал бы запрос и возвращал бы флаг согласно которому импортировался бы тот или иной шаблон…